# добавление python скрипта через launchctl по терминалу

Tags: python, macos, shell, daemon

Есть два компьютера
На втором компьютере есть скрипт пайтона, у моего компьютера есть рутированый доступ к терминалу второго(на нем мак), знаю что можно в автозапуск в маке можно добавить скрипт через launchctl, но можно ли сделать это через терминал? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать свой LaunchAgent.

Если вкратце - вы создаете plist файл с параметрами запуска вашего приложения (bash скрипта, который запускает ваш python скрипт), помещаете его в папку /Library/LaunchAgents/ и активируете командой

`launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourscript.plist`

Вот подробное описание: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

Рекомендую сначала попробовать так запустить какой-нибудь элементарно простой скрипт на вашем компьютере и убедится что он работает правильно, а потом уже создать полноценный скрипт и запустить на удаленном компьютере.